# Prevent setAttribute from running twice

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to snap an element below another element and make it stay put. The function is ok, but it runs every time I move it 10px. So it moves 10px even further each time..

```
   function move_box() {

    if(el.offsetLeft = 10){
        console.log('moved the element 10px to the left!');
        el.setAttribute('class', 'snap_in'); // class with css (transform: translateY(10px)

        let not_called = false; 
        console.log(not_called);

    } else if (not_called = false){
        console.log(not_called);
        el.setAttribute('class', 'dont_move'); //class with css transform:translateY(0px);
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: [you're assigning the values instead of comparing them](https://javascript.info/operators)

Comment: As mentioned you want to get familiar with JS "comparison operators". You will need an "A equals B" check which is "A == B", but do yourself a favour and look that up :)

Comment: replace = by  ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use '==' instead of =

you are assigning not comparing

```
const el = document.querySelector('.item');
let not_called;
el.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);

function mousedown(e){

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

let prevX = e.clientX;
let prevY = e.clientY;

function mousemove(e) {
    let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
    let newY = prevY - e.clientY;

    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    el.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
    el.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

    prevX = e.clientX;
    prevY = e.clientY;  

}
function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
    console.log(el.offsetLeft);
    console.log(el.offsetTop);
    //let leftoffset = el.offsetLeft;
    if (not_called == false){
        console.log(not_called);
        el.setAttribute('class', 'item');
    }
    else if(el.offsetLeft >= 180 && el.offsetLeft <= 220){
        console.log('yes!');
        el.setAttribute('class', 'snap_in');
        not_called = false;
        console.log(not_called);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I added more conditionals, because it was hard to hit exactly 10px. Here is a fiddle: [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/pvfz3w7o/) and still the element is moving...

Comment: check the above updated code for your question. Many other logic errors are there which is not related to question in your code.I dont know what you are creating.Now the item setattribute is calling